# SUMIFS in ARRAYFORMULA adding rows it shouldn't in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sample sheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eIq67HjeOrH8UqWZqtIE5ZhNcfI_lepcL_ADbzVkSzU/edit?usp=sharing.

In the `report` tab I have a formula in `D1`:

```
={
    "Totals";
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        IF(
            A2:A <> "",
            SUMIFS(
                data!E:E,
                data!D:D, "" & C2:C,
                data!C:C, "alpha"
            ),
        )
    )
}
```

The idea is to sum `data!E:E` if `data!D:D` is equal to `report!C2:C` of the array formula and `data!C:C` is equal to `alpha`. `report!C2:C` has a date in `YYYY-MM` text format. And `data!C:C` has the same.

But the formula is returning invalid rows. For example, `data!C:C` does not have `2022-06` but the formula is returning `350` for it.

[image]

Comment: SUMIFS() does not work in Arrayformula() period.

Comment: whats your other criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use SUMIFS() in arrayformula.  You can use SUMIF() though.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Totals";IF(A2:A="",,SUMIF(data!C:C&data!D:D,"alpha"&C2:C,data!E:E))})
```

should work

Comment: I have multiple criteria though...

Comment: your example formula only showed one, what are the other criteria?

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to keep the example simple. I updated the example.

Comment: You can ampersand the criteria together in a SUMIF() see updated answer above @IMTheNachoMan

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY({FILTER(data!D:E, data!C:C="alpha"); 
 FLATTEN({2021, 2022}&"-"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(12), "00")), SEQUENCE(24, 1,,)}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 matches '^(2021.*|2022.*)' group by Col1"), "offset 1", ))
```

[image]